# Use of request.getParameter in JSP results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, liferay

Trying to get a query string parameter and take an appropriate action in a JSP page.

Here is a snippet:

```
<%@ page import="com.companyx.portal.model.LDAPAttributes" %>
<%@ page import="com.companyx.portal.service.LDAPAttributesLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>

<%
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
String screenName = user.getScreenName();
LDAPAttributes attr = LDAPAttributesLocalServiceUtil.getLDAPAttributes(screenName);
String store = attr.getLegacyStoreNo();
String org = request.getParameter("org");
%>

...more code here...

<html>
...html code here...
<form name="LoginForm" action="check_login.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="LOGIN_NAME" size="20" value="<%= store %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="LOGIN_PASSWORD" size="20" value="<%= store %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ORGANIZATION" value="<%= org %>" />
</form>
```

When the following lines are absent:

```
 String org = request.getParameter("org");
 ...
 <input type="hidden" name="ORGANIZATION" value="<%= org %>" />
```

The script works just fine, but I need to capture an 'org' parameter from the query string, write it into the generated form and submit it. When those lines are present, though, I get a 500 error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Clarification: the parameter gets passed to this jsp as ?org=COMMERCIAL and then gets written into a form that posts to an external application as ORGANIZATION. No, I am not that stupid ;-)

Comment: See RP's answer: Keep in mind you're obviously in a portlet environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are you're working with the `PortletRequest` and not the `HttpServletRequest`.

```
HttpServletRequest realRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);

String organization = realRequest.getParameter("org");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String org = request.getParameter("ORGANIZATION");
```

Comment: +1 - OP : the explanation is that your form uses "ORGANIZATION" as the input name not "org" and the input name attribute becomes the parameter name.

Comment: As I added to my question above, this jsp is writing out an intermediary form that posts to a completely different application. This is sort of a "connector" from Liferay to a php app (Dell KBOX). This jsp gets called with this url: /c/portal/kboxtest?org=COMMERCIAL and my struts action *is* properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<input id ="org" type="hidden" name="org" value="" />
```

Then you can add any value to value property.

```
 String org = request.getParameter("org"); // get from input hidden id
```

Comment: This doesn't apply, as I am not getting input to this jsp from the form I am writing out in it. The form I'm writing out is posting to an external app, the parameters I need for processing the jsp have to come from the querystring: /c/portal/kboxtest?org=COMMERCIAL

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing `org` in the query string properly , then your code will work correctly.

And if it is not working properly, use `request.setAttribute("org",org_value)` instead of passing org value as query parameter and get the org value in jsp using `request.getAttribute("org").toString`. It will definitely work.

Comment: I am passing it as a query string property: /c/portal/kboxtest?org=COMMERCIAL , but it is definitely giving a 500 error, with java.lang.NullPointerException. All I get in the Tomcat logs is INFO, no ERROR ... I'm lost.

Comment: Some fix `request.getAttribute("org").toString()`;

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not solved even after trying what Andrew Thompson has asked.
Incase you are using Tomcat, can you try changing the name of "org" variable to something else.
I don't remember exactly but once I have faced a similar problem in one of the versions of Tomcat where "org" variable name was not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I am using Tomcat. I am using this jsp as a sort of "connector" between Liferay and a php application. So I have to construct a link in Liferay to my struts action: /c/portal/kboxtest?org=COMMERCIAL and I am trying to pull that querystring parameter out and write it into a form that posts to the kbox application. And same origin policy does not apply, because I have a similar form that does  the same thing, just no parameter extraction.

Comment: When are you getting NullPointerException? Is it on submission of form check_login.php? I would suggest you to add the following line as well otherwise if org parameter will not be passed in the query string, the value will be null in the org input field,                     org = org != null ? org : "";

Comment: No I was getting the 500 error on accessing the struts action that I set up for that jsp. Problem is that request.getParameter was null no matter what I sent/checked for. SO... I did request.getQueryString and looped through it that way and I'm golden.

Answer (score -1):

if i use request.getParameter() two times in the same jsp page.

for the 2nd time it shows null.

like

```
if(request.getParameter("frmdttxt") != request.getParameter("start_date")){
                    out.println("we are here");
                    date_flag="DNM";                        
                }else{

                    date_flag="DM";
                }




if(request.getParameter("page_number")==null){
                //System.out.println("we are here");
                frmdt = request.getParameter("frmdttxt");
                todt = request.getParameter("todttxt");
                stat = request.getParameter("status");
                regn = request.getParameter("region");

                }
```

then frmdt is null.