# how to get parameter value into a url dynamically from html element

Tags: url, servlets

how to get parameter value into a **url** dynamically from html element?

```
<tbody>
<td id="req">
        <RequestId>
    </td></tbody>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/Project/Emailservlet?id="></a>

String r= request.getParameter("reqid");
```

I want the value of html element id="req" in href.

Comment: I think you miss one **<a>** tag between **<td>**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does request.getParameter return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425305/what-does-request-getparameter-return)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936942/use-of-request-getparameter-in-jsp-results-in-nullpointerexception which shows how to use the result of `request.getParameter`

Comment: I need to pass the value returned in request.getParameter will return the value of <td> tag.. That value should be passed in the url